# Use Generic Protocol to filter array of subviews

Tags: ios, swift, class, generics, protocols

In our app, we have a canvas. The canvas could contain Stickers, Images, Texts, etc. We have a protocol `CanvasItem` that implement the common properties between these items:

```
protocol CanvasItemProtocol{
  var scale : CGFloat { get set }
}

class CanvasItem : CanvasItemProtocol {
   public var scale : CGFloat = 1.0
}
```

Then each class-model (Stickers, Text etc) conform to `CanvasItem`, adding class-specific properties:

```
public class StickerItem: CanvasItem {
  public var stickerName: String
}

public class ShapeItem: CanvasItem {
  public var shapeColor: UIColor
}
```

To show those, we first created a base generic (I think) `UIView` class  that can be inited only with `CanvasItem`:

```
class ViewItem <T: CanvasItemProtocol>: UIView {
let canvasItem: T
init (t: T) {
    self.canvasItem = t
    super .init(frame: .zero)
  }
}
```

and then for each of the models, we create specific `UIView<CanvasItem>` class:

```
class CanvasShapeView: ViewClass<ShapeItem> { }

class CanvasStickerView: ViewClass<StickerItem> { }
```

Then I'm trying to do the following:

```
let superview = UIView()
let shapeView = CanvasStickerView(StickerItem())
let stickerView = CanvasShapeView(ShapeItem())

superview.addSubview(shapeView)
superview.addSubview(stickerView)

for canvasItemView in superview.subviews.compactMap({$0 as? ViewItem<CanvasItem>}) {
   print(canvasItemView.canvasItem.scale) // **access only the common properties**
}
```

**It compiles, but return zero results (the casting not working)**...
  I'm trying to access only to the `CanvasItem` **common properties**.

Gist link:
[Playground.swift](https://gist.github.com/CraftizLtd/a1549db6f3f06389a29033d47a079f1d)

Any suggestions? We stuck on this for a few good days now.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocols and generics in conjunction with subclassing don't work together very well

Actually you don't need neither the protocol nor the view wrapper class. Subclassing `UIView` is sufficient.

```
class CanvasItem : UIView
{
    public var scale : CGFloat = 1.0
}

class StickerItem: CanvasItem
{
    public var stickerName : String = ""
}

class ShapeItem: CanvasItem
{
    public var color: UIColor = .red
}

let shapeItem = ShapeItem()
let stickerItem = StickerItem()
let superview = UIView()
superview.addSubview(shapeItem)
superview.addSubview(stickerItem)

for case let canvasItemView as CanvasItem in superview.subviews {
    print(canvasItemView.scale)
}
```

Comment: Hey Vadian, thank you for responding. Is it possible to still use subclasses `CanvasShapeView`, `CanvasStickerView` for a specific implementations, and still use this mechanism?

Comment: Basically it's impossible to cast the base class `UIView` to the generic type wrapper. A protocol with associated types might be a solution.

Comment: That's the dream, not having to repeat the code in every subclass... If it's not too much to ask (ask I'm battling this for a few days now), could you add a simple-stupid sample? It'll be a great help

Comment: But that's the goal of a base class to implement all the common properties in there and override them in the subclasses. And for common methods which consider the different subclass types a protocol with associated types or even a protocol extension is preferable.

Comment: Forgot to mention one critical thing. I'm so sorry. We use the `CanvasItem` as the model for our DB, so it's inheriting also from `Codable` which won't compile. Is there any chance to still use this mechanism and conform to Codable? I'm sorry for not adding it, I noticed it just one while implementing.

Comment: `Codable` doesn't support inheritance by default. But you can add it by implementing the protocol methods and calling `super` at some point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197774/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-vadian).

Answer (score 1):

Classes `CanvasShapeView` and `CanvasStickerView` share the template of the class, but are completely different classes.

That is why I would check to see whether classes conform to the same template - search for the `canvasItem` as a part of the class, and then try to get the needed value:

```
let test = superview.subviews
    .compactMap({ Mirror(reflecting: $0).children.first(where: { $0.label == "canvasItem" }) })
    .compactMap({ $0.value as? CanvasItemProtocol })
for value in test {
    print(value.scale)
}
```

I had to use reflection in order to do this - not the best solution I guess, but it did the trick.

Comment: Great approach, but not clean enough for production app haha. Thanks tho!

Comment: Yeah, I would be weary of using this in production... Well, at least you now have "plan B" if everything else fails ;)